# Inject ObjectMapper into Spring Kafka serialiser/deserialiser

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I'm using Spring Kafka 1.1.2-RELEASE with Spring Boot 1.5.0 RC and I have configured a custom value serialiser/deserialiser class extending `org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer`/`org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer`.  These classes do use a Jackson `ObjectMapper` which can be provided through the constructor.

Is it somehow possible to inject the `ObjectMapper` from my Spring context?  I have an `ObjectMapper` configured already which I would like to reuse in the serializer/deserializer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can configure `JsonSerializer` and `JsonDeserializer` as `@Bean`s. 
Inject a desired `ObjectMapper` to them. And use those beans in the `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory` and `DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory` bean definitions:

```
    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<Integer, String> producerFactory() {
        DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<Integer, String> producerFactory = 
                new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
        producerFactory.setValueSerializer(jsonSerializer());
        return producerFactory;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that will solve my duplication.  However, regarding the new autoconfiguration for Kafka in Spring Boot 1.5, I suppose I can use `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaProperties#buildProducerProperties` to keep all other configuration working, but wouldn't it still be weird to bypass the configured values for `spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer` then?

Comment: Yes, you have to reuse `buildProducerProper‌​ties()` for your custom bean. And no, `.producer.value-serializer` is for class, which is instantiated by Kafka on demand. If you want to use your own instance you have only choice to inject it directly. See `KafkaProducer(Map<String, Object> configs, Serializer<K> keySerializer, Serializer<V> valueSerializer)` API on the matter.

Answer (score 7):

```
@Component
public class ObjectMapperProducerFactoryCustomizer implements DefaultKafkaProducerFactoryCustomizer {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public ObjectMapperProducerFactoryCustomizer(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public void customize(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<?, ?> producerFactory) {
        if (Objects.nonNull(producerFactory)) {
            producerFactory.setValueSerializer(new JsonSerializer<>(objectMapper));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers. At least explain why it's better this way or what it dives.

Comment: This requires using Spring Boot 2.3.0 or later

Answer (score 2):

For the reactive non-blocking kafka client the configuration is the following:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(KafkaProperties.class)
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean
    public ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate<String, Object> kafkaProducerTemplate(KafkaProperties p,
                                                                               ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return new ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate<>(
                SenderOptions.<String, Object>create(p.buildProducerProperties())
                        .withValueSerializer(new JsonSerializer<>(objectMapper)));
    }
}
```

the above implies that you are using the `io.projectreactor.kafka` dep,

```
dependencies {
    compile "io.projectreactor.kafka:reactor-kafka"
}
```