# Spring Boot inject ObjectMapper into Kafka JsonDeserializer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I would like to inject jackson's ObjectMapper into JsonDeserializer for Kafka's ConsumerFactory. I've done what is mentioned on this post:

[Inject ObjectMapper into Spring Kafka serialiser/deserialiser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41833110/inject-objectmapper-into-spring-kafka-serialiser-deserialiser)

However, when I have multiple `@KafkaListener`s on different topics, the `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` constructs multiple instances of `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer` using the properties map to initialize the `ConsumerFactory`instead of the instance passed into `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.setConsumerFactory()`. Only the first `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer`is using the correct `ConsumerFactory`.

How do I fix this and configure Kafka properly?

Answer (score 1):

You need a different consumer / container factory for each listener. Then use the containerFactory property on @KafkaListener to specify the factory to use.