# Issue with customizing object mapper

Tags: java, spring, jackson, spring-kafka

I am tring produce some message to kafka topic and I want to customize the Jackson ObjectMapper to serialize my `LocalDateTime` as String like this `2021-07-08T16:43:02Z`

But neither this

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration {

    ...

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        return mapper;
    }


}
```

or this

```
spring:
  jackson:
    serialization:
      write-dates-as-timestamps: false
```

has worked,

I get always in the topic a message with field time as

```
"time": [
    2021,
    7,
    8,
    10,
    46,
    29,
    598476000
]
```

application.yaml

```
spring:
  main:
    web-application-type: none

  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: ${KAFKA_SERVERS}
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
...
```

Comment: Yes; when configuring the serializer via kafka properties, Kafka creates it, not Spring. See the answer to that question.

Answer (score 0):

indeed this [Inject ObjectMapper into Spring Kafka serialiser/deserialiser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41833110/inject-objectmapper-into-spring-kafka-serialiser-deserialiser) works but I didn't use the accepted answer

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaCustomizerConf implements DefaultKafkaProducerFactoryCustomizer {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        return mapper;
    }


    @Override
    public void customize(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<?, ?> producerFactory) {
        producerFactory.setValueSerializer(new JsonSerializer<>(objectMapper()));
    }


}
```